# How i upload file to cloudinary using g script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, cloudinary

I want to upload file to cloudinary using Google app script. I wanted to put file using file URL. I don't know how I do this. If anyone does know please reply to me.

Comment: To use external APIs in Google Apps Script server side code you have to use [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). If you need further help, show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in functionality for uploading files to Cloudinary in Google App Script. However, there are a few ways you could do this:

1. Use the Cloudinary Upload API:

You can make a POST request to the Cloudinary Upload API from Google App Script. See the documentation for more information: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api#reference

2. Use a Cloudinary SDK:

There are Cloudinary SDKs available for a variety of languages, including Node.js, PHP, Java, and Python. You could use one of these SDKs to upload files from Google App Script.

3. Use a third-party service:

There are a few third-party services that offer integration with Cloudinary, including Zapier and IFTTT. You could use one of these services to automate the process of uploading files to Cloudinary from Google App Script.

Comment: https://cloudinary.com/documentation

Comment: I don't known how this function implement in google app script. can you  have any code.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have.